# kendoui file upload taking lots of time when website hosted on port 80 in IIS7

Tags: .net, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC5 website hosted on port 80 in IIS7.5 server.

I am using kendoui asynchronous file upload control for uploading files. When I upload a file of size 1MB, it takes lots of time to complete.

I hosted the same website on port 8001 and then file uploaded as expected.

Do I have to configure something in IIS?

Comment: Ummm so strange, exists any other app or process that use the port 80? maybe, a conflict is generated using the port 80

Comment: there is no other process using port 80

Comment: What about the application pools? Did you create a dedicated application pool when hosting on port 8001?